python/asyncio: how to get the exception handler "context"?
I set up a custom exception handler for my asyncio loop.
I know I can call loop.call_exception_handler(context) to use my custom exception handler to trace/log exception I catch in my code using an except: statement, but is there a way to get a context dict as complete as possible, like the one asyncio generates when it calls loop.call_exception_handler (i.e. autodecting all the items usually found in the context)?
If not, is the exception instance caught using except Except as e: good to create a minimal context like:
loop.call_exception_handler({"exception": e})

Did you look at the source code of call_exception_handler at asyncio/base_events.py?

asyncio/base_events.py#call_exception_hander receives the context, it does not generate one using something as the inspect module functions to discover all the parts that can be used to populate context.
